# Getting specific lines in a text file and pass it to an array

Tags: python, python-2.7

Not sure if this has been asked. But here it goes.

Let's say I have a text file containing

```
1 Why
2 We
3 Please
4 OR
5 I
6 AM
7 HUMAN
8 OR
9 MY
10 time
11 to
12 eat
```

Now I want to get lines 5-7 and 9-12 then put it in an array. Do note that the OR word acts like a delimiter in the text file.

I know the usual way of reading a text file in python is using a for loop, but I cant think of a way to do this by using a for loop or any other methods.

Comment: This is probably a stupid question, but does your file actually contain those numbers or do they just represent line numbers

Comment: Do you want line `5` - `7`, or to split by `OR`? Please be clear on this, they are too separate problems

Comment: @jamylak Those are just line numbers. I need to get lines 5-7 which are delimited by OR words.

Comment: Do you just need lines `5 - 7`? Cause then the `OR` makes no difference at all. The answer you have accepted is contrary to this because you ONLY split by OR and completely disregard line numbers

Comment: @jamylak Not only 5-7, I will also need 9-12. See edited question post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do

```
data = open(<textfile>).read()
segments = data.split('OR')
```

and then split the segments by `\n` to get lines in that segment

```
lines = [seg.split("\n") for seg in segments]
```

Comment: closest answer I wanted. Just needed to modify for it to fit my code. Thanks a lot man!

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv;  
import re;  
crs = csv.reader(open("D:/a.txt", "r"));  
line = ""  
for each in crs:  
    line = line + each[0];  

print re.split('OR',line)
```

Answer:

> ['WhyWePlease', 'IAMHUMAN', 'ME']